# Windows change system resolution c++

Tags: windows, qt, winapi

I am trying to change system resolution programatically. What I need to achieve is set system resolution to maximum value.

Below is code the code which change the screen resolution to maximum available value.

```
       DEVMODE devmode = { 0 };

       int i=0;
       QList<int>widths;
       QList<int>heights;
       while (1) {
           if(EnumDisplaySettings( NULL,i, &devmode )!=true)
                break;

           widths.append(devmode.dmPelsWidth);
           heights.append(devmode.dmPelsHeight);

           qDebug()<<devmode.dmPelsWidth<<" X "<<devmode.dmPelsHeight;

           i++;

       }

       EnumDisplaySettings( NULL,ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devmode );

       devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
       devmode.dmPelsWidth = widths.at(widths.size()-1); //take last item maximum value
       devmode.dmPelsHeight = heights.at(widths.size()-1); //take last item maximum value

       long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, DM_PELSWIDTH || DM_PELSHEIGHT);
```

And it works fine when,

1. When the system resolution is maximum(1920x1080) I change to the same value.
2. When the system resolution is higher and I am changed to lower value.

But it doesn't work when I am changing from lower value to higher, like current resolution is 1600X900 and when I am changing to 1920x1080 then it wont work.
And I am getting -2 as return value and which stand for `The graphics mode is not supported` on the doc.

Comment: I assume that you've verified that 1920x1080 is a valid resolution? Also keep in mind that `ChangeDisplaySettings` only changes the _default_  display device. To change a different device you'd need to use [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to change it for monitor connected with the system. I will try  `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`

Comment: If that's the problem, let me know, and I'll write it up as a real answer.

Comment: I tried it but, it also returning -2(The graphics mode is not supported), the code looks like        `long result  = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(NULL,&devmode,NULL, DM_PELSWIDTH || DM_PELSHEIGHT,NULL);`

Comment: You're passing `NULL` as the device name. From the docs: "A NULL value specifies the default display device." Your call to the Ex function exactly matches the non-ex call.

Comment: So shouldn't that work for the default monitor connected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114122/discussion-between-haris-and-theb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the way you're calling the function.

First, there is a typo. `DM_PELSWIDTH || DM_PELSHEIGHT` evaluates to 1, not the combination of the two flags. You probably meant `DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT`

Second, those are not the flags you should be passing to `ChangeDisplaySettings`. Here's the correct way to call the function:

```
DEVMODE desiredMode = { 0 };
desiredMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
desiredMode.dmPelsWidth = 1920;
desiredMode.dmPelsHeight = 1080;
desiredMode.dmFields = DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH;
LONG res = ChangeDisplaySettings(&desiredMode, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | CDS_GLOBAL | CDS_RESET);
```

The `dmFields` member of the `DEVMODE` structure is where you tell the system which fields you want to change.  The flags on `ChangeDisplaySettings` specify how those settings are applied. The reason *why* the call with `DM_PELSWIDTH || DM_PELSHEIGHT` didn't fail with `DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS` is that 1 is the value of the `CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY` flag.

As a side note: if you are just temporarily changing resolution for your application (like games do) then pass the flag `CDS_FULLSCREEN` by itself and it will revert the settings when your application exits. The combination of flags in the example above, sets the settings for all users, stores it in the registry, and applies the change immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got the code somewhere from the net, my bad couldn't figure out that bug, and yes my application need to change the resolution temporarily and I am going to use `CDS_FULLSCREEN`

Comment: One more query when I use `CDS_FULLSCREEN` like `long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, CDS_FULLSCREEN);` the code is working as expected, but when the resolution changed to maximum,  the application window seems not maximized, I have to do that manually. Am I doing the right way in `CDS_FULLSCREEN`

Comment: You're doing it correctly. ChangeDisplaySettings only changes the device's settings, it doesn't do anything to the windows. You'll have to resize/maximize the window yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will do it from my application.